# Can I install `systemctl` onto my Mac?

Tags: systemd, osx, services

On Mac, the alternative to `service` and `systemctl` is `launchctl`. I don’t really like it and am wondering if I can install `systemctl` onto my Mac. Is it possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, Systemd, which systemctl is a part of, is a service manager designed specifically for Linux and uses interfaces and constructs specific to it such as cgroups. There is no port of it to Mac OS.